# Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls Treeview not rendering on some machines

Tags: asp.net, treeview, web-controls

We have a simple web page which displays a treeview ( Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls )

[image: correctly rendered]

Now, on some machines (mainly the clients ones ;-) ) the treeview isn't rendered properly :

[image: not correctly rendered]

I've tested this on all my machines, even linux, and everything is rendered correctly here. I can reproduce this error though by removing or renaming the 'webctrl_client' folder.

I don't understand however what this problem can be? The 'webctrl_client' folder is correctly installed in the root www folder, and the .dll is also properly placed?
I tried clearing the browsers cache but that doesn't seem to have any effect either ....

Doen anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.Treeview` is an obsolete control.

The most likely reason why your tree control breaks is that it does not work on Windows 8/IE10.

Best option is to convert to `System.Web.UI.WebControl.TreeView`

**Quick fix:** add the following code to your `Global.asax.vb.Application_EndRequest`. This will force IE to load your application in compatibility mode.

```
Try

   Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=5")

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

You may also read this article on how to make sure your server recognizes IE10:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

**More explanation:**
Microsoft removed support for HTC behavior files in IE10 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801216(v=vs.85).aspx). HTCs was the old way of extending browser's capabilities. Microsoft TreeView uses HTCs (found in `webctrl_client` folder) with no fallback. Other browsers do still seem to support HTCs.