# Tree view in asp.net not expanding in IE10/win 8

Tags: asp.net

I am using a web application.I have a Tree view i n my site.Its the main Navigation tool to enter in whole site.But the tree view is not expanding in IE 10/Win 8.

Answer (score 0):

Refer :[Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls Treeview not rendering on some machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927236/microsoft-web-ui-webcontrols-treeview-not-rendering-on-some-machines)

Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.Treeview is an obsolete control.

The most likely reason why your tree control breaks is that it does not work on Windows 8/IE10.

Best option is to convert to System.Web.UI.WebControl.TreeView

Quick fix: add the following code to your Global.asax.vb.Application_EndRequest. This will force IE to load your application in compatibility mode.

```
Try

   Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=5")

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```