# Treenode convert Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls to System.Web.UI.WebControls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, treenode, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I'm trying to convert treeview that uses the older htc tag`< iewc:treeview>` to use the newer asp treeview tag  `< asp:TreeView >`. I noticed that the treeview object is different as in the older code uses the import `Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls` compared to the newer code `System.Web.UI.WebControls`. Can someone point me in the right direction of converting these data types easily?

To provide a example where I'm having trouble, the old treenode has members which are not found in the newer treenode . For example I can't seem to find the equilavilant for the member NodeData

```
     myTreeNode.NodeData = "test string"
```

in the treeNode found in `System.Web.UI.WebControls`.

This is the link I used for reference for the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` treeNode
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode(v=vs.100).aspx

However I can't find one for `Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls`.

Comment: When the Ajax toolkit first came out I think the controls were in the Microsoft.web namespace.  Eventually the controls were moved into the .net framework and system.web namespace

Comment: Here's the reference for the [Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529711(v=vs.85).aspx). Scroll way down to find the TreeView link. Here's another link to explain how you can still [live in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16179493/3585500) with IE at least.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!